# Knockout js observableArray nuance

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I had a bug in my code which I have now fixed but left me wondering exactly why it happened.

Issue was that I was pushing using

```
this.reasons().push({ label: reason, value: reason })
```

(reasons is an observable array)

instead of:

```
this.reasons.push({ label: reason, value: reason });
```

which makes sense, however, what completely threw me off the scent is that using a ul tag like :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-bind="foreach: options">
```

works with the first method of pushing to the array but:

```
<select

        data-bind="options: options, value: selected, optionsText: getText, valueAllowUnset: true, optionsAfterRender: processDisabled"></select>
```

does not. My best guess is that knockouts dependancy tracking works differently when using the foreach data-bind and picked up the changes to the array anyway. Using the second method of pushing to the observableArray notifies all listeners regardless of this nuance.

Can anyone confirm explain why and give me the reason why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you evaluate `this.reasons()` you are left with a plain js array, that you push onto. Knockout is not aware of the change, because you are pushing against the vanilla array and not the observableArray instance.

On the second try you are evaluating the observableArray's definition of push, which is, simply put, a "push to the actual array AND callback all functions in an other array, called 'dependencies'"